# Cannot upgrade after installation of xsane

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center, xsane

I have been experiencing problems after installing xsane and other software. I think I've been a bit naughty and I have taken advice from unofficial sources, and now I am reaping the consequences.

[I put this problem to the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310055), and there is a lot of diagnostic information disclosed therein. Although I have received assistance, I haven't been able to restore the feature; although my CPUs appear to be doing something, the Updater appears to hang after the console says that it is "Preconfiguring packages...". The CPU activity remains even after I cancel the update - I have to restart my HP 250 G3 Laptop to make the CPUs settle down.

This is perhaps a trifle inconvenient, and I am perhaps a touch worried that something nasty has happened to my computer. I would just like my Ubuntu to process updates when they are due, and I'm not particularly concerned at this moment about the possibility that I might need to remove some applications so this would happen.

Thank you in advance of your assistance,

Owen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please don't link to other sites with your problem description, but copy-paste it from there onto this site and [format it](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for optimum readability of your question...

Comment: @Fabby I will endeavour to remember to do this in the future. The link I cite discloses a lot of diagnostic information to my problem, and cutting and pasting this information would be difficult on account of the fact that one has also to reformat the markup. The information is held in a source that is as reliable as Stack Exchange, and is no more than a click away; please forgive me this once.

Comment: Oh, I forgive you, but *because* it is difficult to copy-paste, *it is also difficult to read*, so you won't get many answers here. (E.G.: ***I don't even bother to click the link*** if I see a question linked from UbuntuForums because that's more of a discussion site then it is a Q&A site) **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.4 from a USB and have taken a mental note only to use the Software Centre unless doing so is impractical.